# How can I create a RegEx to segment tablet traffic from mobile traffic?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So far I have this: (1\d|[7-9])\d\d+x.*

The problem is, it is still pulling in higher-end smart phones with high screen resolutions.
Can anyone think of any additions to this that would filter out smart phones? Maybe filtering out another dimension with this RegEx?

Thanks!

*a solution to this problem would be nice, but any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Here is some sample data:

```
Mobile Device Info  Screen Resolution
Apple iPad  768x1024
Apple iPhone    320x480
Apple iPhone    320x568
Apple iPod  320x480
(not set)   320x480
(not set)   720x1280
Motorola MOTXT912B Droid Razr 4G    540x960
Samsung GT-I9300 Galaxy S3  720x1280
(not set)   320x568
Samsung SGH-T999 Galaxy S3  720x1280
Samsung SGH-I747 Galaxy S3  720x1280
(not set)   1080x1920
Samsung SPH-L710 Galaxy S3  720x1280
Apple iPod  320x568
(not set)   1440x900
(not set)   540x960
DoCoMo SC-06D Galaxy SIII LTE   720x1280
```

In these cases the Galaxy S3 is getting matched, but I can't finda way to unmatch it without unmatching all of the other tablets.

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample data that people could help you with. It may broaden the amount of people who can help.

Comment: What are you matching against?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are asking...?

Comment: Your regex has to match something (guess it's screen resolution), so I think that is was Evan Knowles is asking.

Comment: yes, that is correct/makes sense now. it is screen resolution

Answer (score 2):

When I look into advanced segments I can select "tablet traffic" (as opposed to "mobile including tablets") as a filter (which if I understand correctly would make your regex unnecessary).